# Check cookie value and rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

I alread opened a thread to this topic but I wrote it very badly which you can find here, also there I tried with PHP header(), now I'm trying it with setcookie():
[Apache Rewrite only if PHP didn't set header()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049085/apache-rewrite-only-if-php-didnt-set-header?noredirect=1#comment79058640_46049085)

This is what I've got:

index.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['ac'])){
        $ac = $_GET['ac'];
        if(isset($_COOKIE['value']) && $_COOKIE['value'] == "pass"){
            header("Location: https://" . $ac);
        } else {
            sleep(5);
            setcookie("value","pass");
            header("Location: https://filter.bernardo.fm/?ac=" . $ac);
            exit();
        }
     } else {
         echo "Direct access to the Filter is forbidden.";
     }
 ?>
```

Apache sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName filter.bernardo.fm
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^filter.bernardo.fm
    RewriteRule (.*) https://filter.bernardo.fm/?ac=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://filter.bernardo.fm/?ac=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName filter.bernardo.fm
    RewriteEngine On
    <If "true">
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !value=pass [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    </If>
    <Else>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^filter.bernardo.fm
    RewriteRule (.*) https://filter.bernardo.fm/?ac=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    </Else>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/filter.bernardo.fm/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/filter.bernardo.fm/privkey.pem
    DocumentRoot /var/www/filter/
    ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
</VirtualHost>
```

So, what I want is, that when no cookie is set, it gets redirected to filter.bernardo.fm, there the cookie gets set and the person gets redirected to the website he/she wanted to go, for example, bernardo.fm

At this moment I'm getting redirected till an error is beeing showed by Chrome "Too many redirects".

I hope you can help me, and I hope you understand what I did till now and what I want to archive.

With great and best regards, BERNARDO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Rewrite only if PHP didn't set header()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049085/apache-rewrite-only-if-php-didnt-set-header)

Comment: Enhance the original post....

Comment: @Axel You mean edit it? It's not anymore with header(). Regards.

Comment: We understand what you want to do, but what's the question for us? Which problems do you have with your current problem?

Comment: @Federkun I'm getting redirected and redirected till Chrome gives an error "Too many redirects", what did I wrong? Regards

Comment: `var_dump($_COOKIE['value'], $_GET['ac']); exit;` if you want know why

Comment: Doing stuff like this often ends up messing things up when the client does not want to accept any cookies. You are potentially not only preventing things from working correctly in normal user’s browsers, but also for bots/search engines that don’t support cookies. // What is the purpose of this in the first place? What is your “filter” supposed to do, that “direct access” to is forbidden?

Comment: Well it should prevent L7floods agains my main website "bernardo.fm" so.. It redirects all requests to filter.bernardo.fm, after it gets a cookie, it gets checked by apache if the cookie's value is set as "pass", if so, the person gets redirected to the website he/she wanted to go. @CBroe

Comment: Has your site been attacked in that way? If so, I’d go for a professional solution (like f.e. Cloudflare hosting), instead of trying to implement half thought-through measures like this.

Comment: Yes it has been attacked in this way, sadly. The person that is doing this knows how to bypass Clodflare, sadly.. So I just wanted to do this little thing, also for me to learn something new. I don't know.. Is there no solution to my code? Maybe I wrote something wrong or something like that. @CBroe Regards